# (pure) C: сравнивание массивов символов

Tags: c, массивы, строки

(учу С)

Прошу помочь в вопросе сравнения строк (массива символов).

1. Юзер вводит команду и я ее считываю:

> char temp_command[256];
>
> fgets(temp_command, sizeof(temp_command),stdin);

2. Хочу сравнить с другой строкой (массивом символов):
   сравниваю этот же temp_command с константой
   char help_cmd_id[4] = {"help"};

> ```
>     if (strcmp(str, help_cmd_id) == 1)
>     {     
>          //true
>     }
>     else
>     {
>          //false
>     }
> ```

В итоге у меня **false**, подозреваю потому что у меня в temp_command у меня вбито

> " help и нулевые байты"

, в help_cmd_id просто

> "help"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сравнивать стркои в таком случае?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что

```
char help_cmd_id[4] = {"help"};
```

неверно - нужно выделять 5 (пять) байт - не забывайте про нулевой завершающий байт!

Во-вторых, `fgets` считывает *и символ новой строки тоже*. Его нужно убирать.

В-третьих, `strcmp` возвращает нуль при равных строках, положительное (не 1! просто - >0) значение, если первая строка "больше" (позже в лексикографическом порядке) второй, и отрицательное (не -1, скажем! просто - отрицательное!) если вторая больше первой.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `strcmp` возвращает 0 если обе строки равны, т.е. вам в условии надо сравнивать не с единицей, а с нулём.